# passing a member function to std::signal

Tags: c++, c++11

I have class A, that has a shutdown method that closes all the sockets that has opened.

I want to have a signal handler to close all the sockets that have been opened at runtime if the user terminates the program. I need something like the code below, but of course, it does not work this way.
I tried something like this,

```
#include <csignal>

struct A
{
    void shutdown() {}
    int a = 0;
};

int main()
{
    A a;
    auto t = [&]()->void {a.shutdown();};
    std::signal(SIGINT, t);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, it can't be done. Signal handlers are too primitive a mechanism to support anything which would satisfy your goal, namely, call a member function on a particular instance of a class.

One way of achieving semi-resemblance is to have a global pointer pointing to currently active instance of the control class, and call member through that global pointer in your signal handler.

Answer (score -1):

You can not pass member function as if they were namespace-level functions.  Either make them static, or wrap them in a namespace-level function with the object passed as user data.

Comment: Ah, right, signal() sets global values and requires parameters to be passed via global variables.  Stick to the use of a static function.